# Azure SQL Database using SQL Server Authentication

Tags: azure-sql-database

Microsoft states in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins that Azure SQL Database can use SQL Server Authentication.  Is this the NTLM protocol-based authentication that one sees in an on-premises SQL Server implementation or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database SQL Server Authentication is a username+password authentication for SQL Database contained database user. This is not the NTLM protocol-based authentication. To create a SQL Server authentication login:

```
CREATE LOGIN Mary WITH PASSWORD = '<strong_password>';
```

Comment: Mike - Thanks.  I should have also listed the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-control-access where MS uses the "This authentication method uses a username and password" verbiage in my original post.  I'll keep looking for some more detail that goes beyond that kind of descriptor used by MS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Login first in master database and then you need to give the access to the database user (read, write, update etc.) in the azure database. You can give access to specific schema as well.

By creating the log in you can authenticate the Azure SQL db

Answer (score 0):

The answer I received from Microsoft is:  SQL Server Authentication.  Essentially what we had in SQL 2000/2005.  Obviously it has been tweaked to accommodate the contained user model.